# Can't set winform in start up

Tags: vb.net

I have several forms but I can't set it as start up. please see image below

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: Check this thread [Form not showing as startup option](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?599914-Form-not-showing-as-startup-option).

Comment: Hi, already rebuild the project and I also repair the vs2022. as for the link, i think we have different problem, as per the image above i can't literally see my forms in startup.

Comment: I have had issues with VS2022 and pre .NET core projects. I now have VS2022 and VS2019 to handle both situations. I hope M$ addresses this soon

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by installing vs2019. originally the system is build with vs2012.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).